# Error uploading ios app?

Tags: xcode, upload

I'm just about to upload my app.

I have read all over the internet and I can't find an answer that makes sense to me of my problem:

I archived my project and tried clicking "distribute" and clicked the option in the middle, which got me a .ipa file, I think. I tried using it in Application Loader, but only got this error:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a valid provisioning profile for the app?

Comment: Do you have your app store distribution profile installed on your machine?  If so, select it before you distribute.

Answer (score 0):

### Here's how to upload an app to the App Store (Xcode 4):

1. Make sure you have the correct certificates to sign your app build. Google it if you're not sure.
2. Make sure that Xcode is directed toward an iOS device (top left corner)
3. Build > Archive
4. Open the Organizer to the Archives tab.
5. Click 'Distribute'
6. Fill in your Identity details
7. Follow the steps.

### IF YOU GET AN ERROR

Usually, errors are something like 'your bundle ID is wrong' or 'bundle version bla bla bla'. **These errors look very scary. They are not.** Usually, you can just Google the error. Or comment here for help.

#### If the error is related to code signing

Welcome to the real world. I spent 2 *months* trying to figure this out. Comment here for help.

EDIT: Noticed your problem was with code signing. Under ***< your project >* > *< your target >* >Build Settings > Code Signing > Code Signing Identity**, play with the values until you find something that works. This often means that your bundle ID doesn't match the one on the certificate, etc. Sometimes you have to make certificates through the Provisioning Portal. For any more help, comment here.